# Accessing specific element in std::deque

Tags: c++, deque

I need to access an element at an specific position in the deque "queArr". From this element, which is an object of class "plane" I need to call the member function getTime which returns the private member time. The problem is that I don't know how to access the element since it could be anywhere in the que.

I have tried using the [] operator and que.at() function, both without success. These are the only options I could find in the definition of deque (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) which seemed relevant.

This is the current code. It grabs the position of the element with the lowest fuel (accessed through getFuel()) and then removes it by .erease(pos) using the position added to an iterator pointing to the ques first element. Before this, at the place of the comment, I need to access the member function getTime of this element and add this to the variable totalArr. How to access this is my current problem.

```
//namespace std is being used

landingDelay+=landingTime;
cout<<"A plane has started landing \n";
int quePos=0;
int ref=queArr.front().getFuel(); 
for(int j=0; j<queArr.size(); j++)
{
    if(queArr.at(j).getFuel()<ref)
    {
        ref=queArr.at(j).getFuel();
        quePos=j;
    }
}
it=queArr.begin();
it+=quePos;
//I was thinking something here
queArr.erase(it);
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: *"I have tried using the [] operator and que.at() function, both without success."* Please elaborate on how it didn't work. Please show what you tried, what you expected it to do, what it actually did and explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the STL function [`std::min_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) instead of hand-rolling the same functionality:

```
const auto minFuel = min_element( begin( queArr ), end( queArr ),
    []( const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.getFuel() < b.getFuel(); } );
if( minFuel != end( queArr ) )
{
    cout << minFuel->getTime();
}
```

Here's a complete working example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

struct Plane
{
  Plane( int fuel ) : _fuel{ fuel } {}
  int getFuel() const { return _fuel; }
  int getTime() const { return _fuel * 2; }

private:
  int _fuel;
};

int main()
{
  const auto queArr  = deque<Plane>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 10 };
  const auto minFuel = min_element( begin( queArr ), end( queArr ),
    []( const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.getFuel() < b.getFuel(); } );
  if( minFuel != end( queArr ) )
  {
    cout << minFuel->getTime();
  }
}
```

which outputs `-2`. See it live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b0f5eed95cd1e3c)</kbd>.

Comment: Compiler returns "Error: 'auto' is not allowed here" at the const auto& a and b, Any idea to why this could be?

Comment: Not sure what compiler it version you're using, but `auto` requires C++11 or newer and using it in lambdas requires C++14. You may want to add `-std=c++14` or similar to your command line. You can see my command line, where the example works, in the Coliru link.

Comment: Alternately, change the `auto`s in the lambda to `Plane`.